# How To Create Checking Method To Check The User Input Is Match With The ID provided?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new with JavaScript but I try to illustrate what actually I want to make.

Let's say there's a input to allow user to add the arrays as below:

**[user maybe type any id such as: 12345] [button]**

**purchase ids: [ ]**

But then the existing purchase ID are only have these 4 arrays.

**Purchase ID: [24149,24223,24251,24253]**

**Expected Result**: Once the user click the button, then a checking will do to inform whether the input ID is matchable with the existing purchase id, if not match then display error message to user.

**Question**: Therefore, my question is how can i create a checking method to check the user input is matchable with the existing purchase ID?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="test" v-model="text" placeholder="type here"/><v-btn @click="tick()"small color="rgba(10,0,0,0)">click</v-btn><br>
```

Scripts:

```
data(){
  return{
   selected: [],
   text:''
  }
},
methods:{
   tick(){
   var array = this.text.split(" ");
   array.forEach((item, index)=>{
   this.selected.push(parseInt(item)) 
  })
   this.text = '';
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are splitting the input text. Do you allow user to enter more than one ID per input? In any case you can check for an input data this way:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
      text: '',
      purchase_ids: [24149, 24223, 24251, 24253]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkInput() {
      if (this.purchase_ids.indexOf(parseInt(this.text)) > -1)
        console.log(`ID ${this.text} exists`);
      else
        console.log(`ID does not exists`);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <input type="text" name="test" v-model="text" placeholder="type here" />
  <button @click="checkInput()" small color="rgba(10,0,0,0)">click</button><br>
</div>
```